# how to send svg to php (server side)?

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I am using RaphaelJs to draw SVG images.
Now the question is How i can send the SVG to server side?
And how to handle it on server side using php?

Actually i want to convert SVG to PNG and am using Batik for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you going

http://www.benbarnett.net/2010/06/04/export-svg-from-raphael-js-to-create-a-png-bitmap/

I think it actually does what you are asking exactly.